# Problema unique_together en relacion M2M Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo una relacion M2M entre Grupos y Equipos.
Como un Equipo solo puede ser inscrito en un Grupo, añadí en el meta la restriccion `unique_together = [['group', 'team']]` ([lo vi en la documentacion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/))

me está arrojando un error, al momento de hacer el migrate:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo definidos estos modelos.

Team
[image: TeamModel]

Group
[image: GroupModel]

GroupTeam
[image: GroupTeamModel]

Espero mue puedan ayudar
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Guíate de la manera en la que django trata las relaciones m2m entre tablas, hay ejemplos claros entre el modelo User, Groups y Permissions

[Lo tienes acá](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/)

Siguiendo esa documentación, Puedes usar Sólo un foreignkey group_id en el modelo Team, y quitas el ManyToManyField del modelo Group. Si lo haces así, también podrías quitar el modelo GroupTeam, ya que django lo creará internamente de manera automática (group_team).

Entonces, cuando vayas a agregar un team al grupo, primero revisas que el  team no pertenezca al group:

```
team = Team.objects.get(id=id)
group = Group.objects.get(id=id)

if team not in group.team.all():

    group.team.add(team)
```

[Puedes esa explicación más a fondo acá](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)